# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n+k}{k} \binom{2n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} \frac{1}{k+1} = 0. $

Tags: summation, permutations, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that
>   $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n+k}{k} \binom{2n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} \frac{1}{k+1} = 0.
> $$

I am trying to solve this by using induction on $n$. I have proven the sum to be zero in the case $n=1$. Assuming that the sum is zero for $n=m$ ($m$ is a positive integer), how do I prove that it implies that the sum is zero for $n=m+1$?

Can I get some hints?

Answer (score 5):

Starting from

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n+k\choose k} {2n\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} \frac{1}{k+1}$$

we get

$$\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n+k\choose k+1} {2n\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}
= \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n+k\choose 2n-1} {2n\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} [z^{2n-1}] (1+z)^{2n+k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2n} [z^{2n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n\choose k} 
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} (1+z)^{k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2n} [z^{2n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\left(1-\frac{1}{2} (1+z)\right)^{2n}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}n} [z^{2n-1}] (1+z)^{2n} (1-z)^{2n}
= \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}n} [z^{2n-1}] (1-z^2)^{2n} = 0.$$

The  last  step is  zero  by  inspection  since  we are  extracting  a
coefficient on an odd power from a polynomial where all the powers are
even, and we have the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let's approach the sum through the [Hypergeometric Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).
To this purpose let's rewrite it as
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(n) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,2n} \right)} {\binom{2n+k}{k} \binom{2n}{k} 
{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } \over {2^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,2n} \right)} {\binom{2n+k}{k} \binom{2n}{k} 
 {1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}}\left( { - {1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,2n} \right)} {t_{\,k} \left( { - {1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$

The $t_k$ are in the following ratio
$$
\eqalign{
  & t_{\,0}  = 1  \cr 
  & {{t_{\,k + 1} } \over {t_{\,k} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {2n + k + 1} \right)!} \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)!\left( {k + 1} \right)!\left( {2n - k - 1} \right)!\left( {k + 2} \right)}}
  {{k!k!\left( {2n - k} \right)!\left( {k + 1} \right)} \over {\left( {2n + k} \right)!}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - {{\left( {k + 2n + 1} \right)\left( {k - 2n} \right)} \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)}}{1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}} \cr} 
$$
so the sum can be expressed as
$$
\eqalign{
 & S(n) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,2n} \right)} {\binom{2n+k}{k} \binom{2n}{k} 
{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } \over {2^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {2n + 1,\; - 2n}  \cr    2  \cr  } \,} \right|1/2} \right) \cr} 
$$

For $n=0$ this gives
$$
S(0) = {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {1,\;0}  \cr    2  \cr  } \,} \right|1/2} \right) = 1
$$
while for $0<n$ we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{    {2n + 1,\; - 2n}  \cr     2  \cr   } \,} \right|1/2} \right)\quad \left| {\;0 < n} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( 2 \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2n + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( { - 2n} \right)}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,}
 {{{\Gamma \left( {2n + 1 + k} \right)\Gamma \left( { - 2n + k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2 + k} \right)}}} {1 \over {2^{\,k} k!}} \cr} 
$$

Note that we can arrive to the same result by expressing the binomials through the Gamma function and
performing some algebraic simplifications.

To the fraction outside the sum we can apply the Reflection formula for the Gamma function,
which in the inverted form is valid all over the complex field
$$
{1 \over {\Gamma \left( {z + 1} \right)\,\Gamma \left( { - z} \right)}} =  - {{\sin \left( {\pi \,z} \right)} \over \pi }\quad \left| {\;\forall z \in \mathbb C} \right.
$$
then clearly
$$
S(n)\quad \left| {\;0 < n \in Z} \right. = \sin \left( {2\pi \,n} \right) \cdot \left(  \cdots  \right) = 0
$$

Comment: If you use the binomial theorem for closed Form it's not quite clear to me how to proceed. Can you give a hint?

Comment: @Diger: I found an alternative approach that looks easier (to my opinion)

Comment: I prefered your other approach, which seemed easier as you made it look as if there is not much left to do.

Comment: In fact the zero outside the sum is canceled by the pole inside the sum up to $k=2n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Residue Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+k}{k}\binom{2n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\frac1{k+1}
&=\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{-2n-1}{k}\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\frac1{2^k}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{-2n-1}{k}\binom{2n+1}{2n-k}\frac1{2^k}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\left[x^{2n}\right]\left(1+\frac x2\right)^{-2n-1}(1+x)^{2n+1}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\left[x^{-1}\right]\left(\frac1{x+2}+\frac1x\right)^{2n+1}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
So, we are interested in the residue at $x=0$ of
$$
f(x)=\left(\frac1{x+2}+\frac1x\right)^{2n+1}\tag2
$$
which is the same as the residue at $x=0$ of
$$
-f(-x)=\left(\frac1{x-2}+\frac1x\right)^{2n+1}\tag3
$$
Since $-f(-x)=f(x-2)$, this is the residue of $f(x)$ at $x=-2$.

Thus, the residues of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ and $x=-2$ are equal.

For $|x|\gt2$, $|f(x)|\le\left(\frac2{|x|-2}\right)^{2n+1}$, and for $n\ge1$, $$
\left|\int_{|x|=R}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le2\pi R\left(\frac2{R-2}\right)^{2n+1}\stackrel{R\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\tag4
$$
Thus, [Cauchy's Residue Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) says the sum of the residues is $0$. Therefore, for $n\ge1$, we get that both residues are $0$.

This means that for $n\ge1$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+k}{k}\binom{2n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\frac1{k+1}=0\tag5
$$

---

**A More Elementary Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+k}{k}\binom{2n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\frac1{k+1}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+k}{2n}\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\left(-\frac12\right)^k\tag6\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left[x^{2n}\right](1+x)^{2n+k}\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\left(-\frac12\right)^k\tag7\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\left[x^{2n}\right](1+x)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\left(-\frac{1+x}2\right)^k\tag8\\
&=-\frac2{2n+1}\left[x^{2n}\right](1+x)^{2n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\left(-\frac{1+x}2\right)^{k+1}\tag9\\
&=-\frac2{2n+1}\left[x^{2n}\right](1+x)^{2n-1}\left[\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^{2n+1}-1\right]\tag{10}\\
&=-\frac2{2n+1}\left[x^{2n}\right]\left[\left(\frac{1-x^2}2\right)^{2n-1}\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^2-(1+x)^{2n-1}\right]\tag{11}\\
&=-\frac2{2n+1}\left[x^{2n}\right]\left[\left(\frac{1-x^2}2\right)^{2n-1}\frac{1+x^2}4\right]\tag{12}\\
&=-\frac{2^{-2n}}{2n+1}\left(\left[x^{2n}\right]\left(1-x^2\right)^{2n-1}+\left[x^{2n-2}\right]\left(1-x^2\right)^{2n-1}\right)\tag{13}\\[6pt]
&=-\frac{2^{-2n}}{2n+1}\left((-1)^n\binom{2n-1}{n}+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\right)\tag{14}\\[12pt]
&=0\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(6)$: $\binom{2n+k}{k}=\binom{2n+k}{2n}$ and $\frac1{k+1}\binom{2n}{k}=\frac1{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k+1}$
$\phantom{1}(7)$: $\binom{2n+k}{2n}=\left[x^{2n}\right](1+x)^{2n+k}$
$\phantom{1}(8)$: move $(1+x)^k$ inside the sum
$\phantom{1}(9)$: move $-\frac2{1+x}$ outside the sum
$(10)$: Binomial Theorem
$(11)$: distribute $(1+x)^{2n-1}$
$(12)$: toss out odd powers and powers too small (if $n\ge1$)
$(13)$: $\left[x^{2n}\right]x^2f(x)=\left[x^{2n-2}\right]f(x)$
$(14)$: Binomial Theorem
$(15)$: evaluate

Comment: Why does follow from $|f(x)|\sim\left(\frac2{|x|}\right)^{2n+1}$ that the sum of residues is zero?

Comment: [Cauchy's Residue Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Comment: Is that a joke? So are you saying about $x=0$ you can neglect all the terms from $1/(x+2)$ in the expansion to calculate the residues?

Comment: @Diger: There are two singularities of $f(x)$: one at $x=0$ and one at $x=-2$. The integral of $f(x)$ around a circle $|x|=R$, for $R\gt2$, is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $f(x)$ at those singularities. Since a simple bound of that integral vanishes as $R\to0$, that integral must be $0$ (for all $R\gt2$). Thus, the sum of the residues is $0$. Since the residue at $x=0$ is equal to the residue at $x=-2$, both must be $0$.

Comment: You mean as $R\rightarrow\infty$, or? I guess that was what confused me in the first place. Thx

Comment: Yes, that should have been $R\to\infty$.

Comment: @Diger: thanks for the questions. I have included some of this information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Marko Riedels result, since it doesn‘t require prerequisites, but for the record:

$$
\sum\limits_{ {0 \le } k { \le 2n} } {\binom{2n+k}{2n} \binom{2n}{k} {{\left( \frac{ - t}{2} \right)^{k} }}} = P_{2n}(1-t)
$$
with the Legendre Polynomial $P_{2n}$. It is not too difficult to show, by using the recurrence for the Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$ i.e.
$$
0 = (n+1) P_{n+1}(x) - (2n+1)xP_n(x) + nP_{n-1}(x) \, .
$$
Plugging in the above expression for $n$ instead of $2n$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \left(\frac{-t}{2}\right)^k \Bigg\{ &(n+1) \binom{n+1+k}{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} - 2(2n+1) \binom{n+k-1}{n} \binom{n}{k-1} \\
&-(2n+1) \binom{n+k}{n} \binom{n}{k} + n \binom{n-1+k}{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \Bigg\} = 0
\end{align}
which vanishes termwise after some lengthy but not difficult algebra after converting to factorials; here $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k>n$.
Then
$$
\int_0^1 P_{2n}(1-t) \, {\rm d}t = \int_0^1  P_{2n}(t) \, {\rm d}t = \frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n)!} \frac{{\rm d}^{2n-1}}{{\rm d}t^{2n-1}} \left( t^2 -1\right)^{2n} \Bigg|_{t=0}^{t=1} = 0
$$
by Rodrigues formula and the fact that an odd number of derivatives always leaves at least a single $t$ in each term and since $2n-1 < 2n$ each term will also contain a factor $(t^2-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{%
\left.\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{2n}{2n + k \choose k}{2n \choose k}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2^{k}}{1 \over k + 1}
\,\right\vert_{\large\ n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ >\ 0}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{2n}
{2n \choose k}\braces{\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n + k}}
\int_{0}^{-1/2}t^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\bracks{z^{0}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n}\int_{-1/2}^{0}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{2n}
{2n \choose k}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}t \over z}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\bracks{z^{0}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n}\int_{-1/2}^{0}
\bracks{1 + {\pars{1 + z}t \over z}}^{2n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2n +1}\bracks{z^{2n}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 1}
\bracks{2^{-2n}\pars{1 - z}^{2n + 1} + 2z^{2n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2^{2n}\pars{2n +1}}\bracks{z^{2n}}
\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 1}\pars{1 - z}^{2n + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2^{2n}\pars{2n - 1}}\bracks{z^{2n}}
\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{2n -1}\pars{1 - 2z + z^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2^{2n}\pars{2n +1}} \times
\\[2mm] &\
\!\!\!\!\!\braces{\bracks{z^{2n}}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{2n - 1} -
2\bracks{z^{2n - 1}}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{2n - 1} +
\bracks{z^{2n - 2}}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{2n - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2^{2n}\pars{2n +1}}
\bracks{{2n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}
+
\underbrace{{2n - 1 \choose n - 1}}_{\ds{=\ {2n - 1 \choose n}}}
\pars{-1}^{n - 1}} =
\bbx{\large 0} \\ &
\end{align}