# Calculate $\sum_{k=l}^{2n} \binom{2n+k}{2k} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(k-l)!} (-1)^k$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I'm trying to proof that
$$\sum_{k=l}^{2n} \binom{2n+k}{2k} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(k-l)!} (-1)^k = \begin{cases} 0 \quad {\rm if} \, \, l \, \,{\rm odd} \\ \frac{(-1)^{n-l/2}(2n+l)!}{4^n \left(n-\frac{l}{2}\right)! \left(n+\frac{l}{2}\right)!} \quad {\rm if} \, \, l \, \,{\rm even} \end{cases}$$
where $()!$ is factorial and $()!!$ double-factorial.
Any idea?

edit: Before down-voting it would be more helpful to state what information is missing, but that is probably too much to ask...

**some background:** The question arose when I tried to solve [Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n+k}{k} \binom{2n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} \frac{1}{k+1} = 0. $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046755/prove-that-sum-k-02n-binom-2nkk-binom2nk-frac-1k2k-f/3048924#3048924)

So the objective was proving that $$\sum\limits_{ {0 \le } k { \le 2n} } {\binom{2n+k}{2n} \binom{2n}{k} {{\left( \frac{t-1}{2} \right)^{k} }}} = P_{2n}(t)$$ which I now tackled differently. But I was wondering why the straight forward way was so difficult. That is I used the binomial theorem for the inner power $$(t-1)^k=(-1)^k\sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l} (-t)^l$$ and then interchanged summation order to obtain
$$\sum_{l=0}^{2n} \frac{(-t)^l}{l!} \sum_{k=l}^{2n} \binom{2n+k}{2k} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(k-l)!} (-1)^k = P_{2n}(t)$$
after some manipulations with the binomial coefficients. So by comparison with the textbook Legendre-form
$$P_{2n}(t)=\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{t^{2l}}{(2l)!} \frac{(-1)^{n-l}(2n+2l)!}{4^n(n+l)!(n-l)!}$$
I concluded the above relation.

Comment: I have not down-voted, but perhaps is because you haven't include any information, like how did you encounter this problem? Or how did you obtain the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{k=q}^{2n} {2n+k\choose 2k}
\frac{(2k-1)!}{(k-1)! \times 2^{k-1}} \frac{1}{(k-q)!} (-1)^k
\\ = \sum_{k=q}^{2n} {2n+k\choose 2k}
\frac{(2k)!}{k! \times 2^{k}} \frac{1}{(k-q)!} (-1)^k
.$$

This is

$$q! \sum_{k=q}^{2n} {2n+k\choose 2k}
\frac{(2k)!}{k! \times k!  \times 2^{k}} 
\frac{k!}{q!\times(k-q)!} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}
\\ = q! \sum_{k=q}^{2n} {2n+k\choose 2k}
{2k\choose k} {k\choose q}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}.$$

Observe that

$${2n+k\choose 2k} {2k\choose k}
= \frac{(2n+k)!}{(2n-k)! \times k! \times k!}
= {2n+k\choose 2n} {2n\choose k}$$

and furthermore

$${2n\choose k} {k\choose q}
= \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-k)! \times q! \times (k-q)!}
= {2n\choose q} {2n-q\choose k-q}.$$

We get for the sum

$${2n\choose q} q! 
\sum_{k=q}^{2n} {2n+k\choose 2n} {2n-q\choose k-q}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}
\\ = {2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-q} {2n+q+k\choose 2n} {2n-q\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}
.$$

This becomes

$${2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-q} {2n+q+k\choose 2n} [z^{2n-q-k}] (1+z)^{2n-q}
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}
\\ = {2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n-q}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-q} {2n+q+k\choose 2n} 
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} z^k.$$

Now  we  may extend  $k$  beyond  $2n-q$  because of  the  coefficient
extractor $[z^{2n-q}]$ (no contribution) and get

$${2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n-q}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {2n+q+k\choose 2n} 
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} z^k
\\ = {2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n-q} [w^{2n}] (1+w)^{2n+q}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (1+w)^k
\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} z^k
\\ = {2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n-q} [w^{2n}] (1+w)^{2n+q}
\frac{1}{1+z(1+w)/2}.$$

Re-write this as

$${2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
[w^{2n}] (1+w)^{2n+q}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{2n-q+1}} (1+z)^{2n-q}
\frac{1}{1+z(1+w)/2}.$$

Working with the residue we apply the substitution $z/(1+z) = v$
or $z=v/(1-v)$ to get

$$\mathrm{Res}_{v=0} \frac{1}{v^{2n-q}} 
\frac{1-v}{v} \frac{1}{1+(v/(1-v))(1+w)/2} \frac{1}{(1-v)^2}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{v=0} \frac{1}{v^{2n-q+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-v+v(1+w)/2}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{v=0} \frac{1}{v^{2n-q+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-v(1-w)/2}
= \frac{1}{2^{2n-q}} (1-w)^{2n-q}.$$

Substitute into the remaining coefficient extractor to get

$${2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}
[w^{2n}] (1+w)^{2n+q} \frac{1}{2^{2n-q}} (1-w)^{2n-q}
\\ =  {2n\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q} (-1)^p {2n-q\choose p} {2n+q\choose 2n-p}.$$

Now

$${2n\choose q} {2n-q\choose p}
= \frac{(2n)!}{q!\times p! \times (2n-q-p)!}
= {2n\choose p} {2n-p\choose q}$$

and

$${2n-p\choose q} {2n+q\choose 2n-p}
= \frac{(2n+q)!}{q! \times (2n-p-q)! \times  (p+q)!}
= {2n+q\choose q} {2n\choose p+q}.$$

This yields

$${2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q} (-1)^p {2n\choose p} {2n\choose p+q}
\\ = {2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q} (-1)^p {2n\choose p} 
[z^{2n-p-q}] (1+z)^{2n}
\\ = {2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q} (-1)^p {2n\choose p} z^p.$$

Now  we  may  extend  $p$  beyond $2n-q$  because  of  the  coeffcient
extractor $[z^{2n-q}]$ in front. We find

$${2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{p\ge 0} (-1)^p {2n\choose p} z^p
\\ = {2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
[z^{2n-q}] (1+z)^{2n} (1-z)^{2n}
\\ = {2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
[z^{2n-q}] (1-z^2)^{2n}.$$

Concluding we immediately obtain zero when $q$ is odd, and otherwise
we find

$${2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
[z^{2(n-q/2)}] (1-z^2)^{2n}
\\ = {2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
[z^{n-q/2}] (1-z)^{2n}.$$

This is

$${2n+q\choose q} q! \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n}}
(-1)^{n-q/2} {2n\choose n-q/2}$$

or alternatively
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{(-1)^{n+q/2}}{2^{2n}}
\frac{(2n+q)!}{(n-q/2)! \times (n+q/2)!}.}$$

Comment: Thanks very much, I really appreciate and start to like that coefficient extractor method ;)

Comment: @Diger Thank you for the kind remark. You might want to add some context if it was useful to you, so it gets re-opened.